# How to calculate a -step transitions of a Discrete-time Markov Chain for Figure 17.1 (b) in book "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective"

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, mathematical-statistics, markov-process

chapter 17 of the book "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective" gives this figure

[image]

> which is the probability of getting from i to j in exactly n steps.
>   Obviously A(1) = A.

In the case of Figure 17.1 (b), the probability of getting from node 1 to node 3 in exactly 2 steps is

$A_{13}(2) = A_{12}(1)A_{23}(1)$

Is that correct?

Comment: Although it's correct, it's not very illuminating.  The nature of the situation starts becoming apparent when you increase the number of steps.

Comment: You can get $n$-step transitions from discrete markov chain by exponentiating the transition matrix

Comment: @logistic do you mean this. $A(n)=A^n$ ?

Comment: Yes @czlsws that's what I mean

Comment: @logistic thanks for your comments. And how to apply that on "Figure 17.1 (b) node 1 to node 3"